# Flexslider not responding to its script?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider, autoplay

I'm setting up a wordpress site and use the flexslider 2.0 for som slideshows on a page. My problem is that I can't seem to get slideshows to respond to the changes I make in their script... i.e. I set the '`slideshow: false,`' but the slieshows still autoplay on the page. None of the other changes I make in the code seems to have an effect either.

The site is:
http://bjornkamdesign.no/?page_id=7

I'm guessing the problem is in the `<head>` but I have no idea where to begin!

This is from my jquery.flexslider.js file

```
  //FlexSlider: Default Settings
  $.flexslider.defaults = {
    namespace: "flex-",             //{NEW} String: Prefix string attached to the class of every element generated by the plugin
    selector: ".slides > li",       //{NEW} Selector: Must match a simple pattern. '{container} > {slide}' -- Ignore pattern at your own peril
    animation: "slide",              //String: Select your animation type, "fade" or "slide"
    easing: "swing",               //{NEW} String: Determines the easing method used in jQuery transitions. jQuery easing plugin is supported!
    direction: "horizontal",        //String: Select the sliding direction, "horizontal" or "vertical"
    reverse: false,                 //{NEW} Boolean: Reverse the animation direction
    animationLoop: true,             //Boolean: Should the animation loop? If false, directionNav will received "disable" classes at either end
    smoothHeight: false,            //{NEW} Boolean: Allow height of the slider to animate smoothly in horizontal mode
    startAt: 0,                     //Integer: The slide that the slider should start on. Array notation (0 = first slide)
    slideshow: false,               //Boolean: Animate slider automatically
    slideshowSpeed: 2000,           //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
    animationSpeed: 600,            //Integer: Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds
    initDelay: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Set an initialization delay, in milliseconds
    randomize: false,               //Boolean: Randomize slide order

    // Usability features
    pauseOnAction: true,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when interacting with control elements, highly recommended.
    pauseOnHover: true,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when hovering over slider, then resume when no longer hovering
    useCSS: true,                   //{NEW} Boolean: Slider will use CSS3 transitions if available
    touch: true,                    //{NEW} Boolean: Allow touch swipe navigation of the slider on touch-enabled devices
    video: false,                   //{NEW} Boolean: If using video in the slider, will prevent CSS3 3D Transforms to avoid graphical glitches

    // Primary Controls
    controlNav: true,               //Boolean: Create navigation for paging control of each clide? Note: Leave true for manualControls usage
    directionNav: true,             //Boolean: Create navigation for previous/next navigation? (true/false)
    prevText: "Forrige",           //String: Set the text for the "previous" directionNav item
    nextText: "Neste",               //String: Set the text for the "next" directionNav item

    // Secondary Navigation
    keyboard: false,                 //Boolean: Allow slider navigating via keyboard left/right keys
    multipleKeyboard: false,        //{NEW} Boolean: Allow keyboard navigation to affect multiple sliders. Default behavior cuts out keyboard navigation with more than one slider present.
    mousewheel: false,              //{UPDATED} Boolean: Requires jquery.mousewheel.js (https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) - Allows slider navigating via mousewheel
    pausePlay: false,               //Boolean: Create pause/play dynamic element
    pauseText: "Pause",             //String: Set the text for the "pause" pausePlay item
    playText: "Play",               //String: Set the text for the "play" pausePlay item

    // Special properties
    controlsContainer: "",          //{UPDATED} jQuery Object/Selector: Declare which container the navigation elements should be appended too. Default container is the FlexSlider element. Example use would be $(".flexslider-container"). Property is ignored if given element is not found.
    manualControls: "",             //{UPDATED} jQuery Object/Selector: Declare custom control navigation. Examples would be $(".flex-control-nav li") or "#tabs-nav li img", etc. The number of elements in your controlNav should match the number of slides/tabs.
    sync: "",                       //{NEW} Selector: Mirror the actions performed on this slider with another slider. Use with care.
    asNavFor: "",                   //{NEW} Selector: Internal property exposed for turning the slider into a thumbnail navigation for another slider

    // Carousel Options
    itemWidth: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Box-model width of individual carousel items, including horizontal borders and padding.
    itemMargin: 0,                  //{NEW} Integer: Margin between carousel items.
    minItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Minimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when below this.
    maxItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Maxmimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when above this limit.
    move: 0,                        //{NEW} Integer: Number of carousel items that should move on animation. If 0, slider will move all visible items.
```

Comment: Please show more code. `slideshow: false` isn't enough.

Comment: where have you set slideshow: false in page

Comment: I have set slideshow: false in the flexslide script .js file

Answer (score 1):

There could be some override in the frontend level, something like:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(window).load(function(){
     jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
        slideshow: true,  
        });
    <script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.
and I changed in frontend and solved .

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.flexslider').flexslider({
         slideshow: false
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.webtechresources.com/2012/01/flexslider-jquery-slider-plugin/) a list of other options the you may use.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.